# Inheritance and member-function templates overloading

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overloading

I try to compile the following code with clang (version 3.0), but it gives me this error

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'a'
```

in the call `__a.a<0>()`. Then I try with g++ (version 4.2.1) and it compiles and works as expected (print out `1 2`).

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  template <int> int a() { return 1; }
};

struct B: A {
  using A::a;
  template <int,int> int a() { return 2; }
};

int main(int, char **) {
  B __a;
  std::cout << __a.a<0>() << " "  << __a.a<0,0>() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I try to look to the standard but I have not found anything that explains which is the correct behavior of compiler. Now, my question is which is the correct behavior, and if clang works correctly, how I can modify my code to work as expected?

Comment: intriguing. Have no working clang setup a.t.m. but it looks like it could be a bug. Try to avoid `__a` naming: names starting with underscores are _reserved_ by the standard.

Comment: FWIW, MSVC10 and GCC 4.4.5 compile just fine too, while Clang 3.1 rejects the code aswell. Also, it definitly has to do with the `using A::a;`, putting the function template directly into `B` clears the error.

Comment: @sehe just a curiosity, have you tried to compile my code? and which compiler have you used?

Comment: @mattia.penati: only g++ 4.4 through g++-4.6.1 quickly (with and without -std=c++0x)

Comment: g++ appears to be doing the right thing. I'm curious if you tried to move the function `a()` from `A` directly into `B`, rather than `using` it? In other words, is it related to inheritance + using, or is it a simple name resolution issue?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: See my comment.

Comment: @Xeo I know that putting the two methods in the same class resolve this problem, but I want to use this pattern in my code and allows me to avoid a lot of changes. So I'm curious to know if it's possible.

Comment: @mattia: I just wanted to pin down the point of failure. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging through both the C++03 and C++11 standard, it doesn't look good for your code to be valid and well-formed. C++03 seems to have allowed this, while a change in the wording of the C++11 standard seems to have disallowed this.

`§7.3.3 [namespace.udecl] (Both standards)`

> p12 (C++03) When a *using-declaration* brings names from a base class into a derived class scope, member functions in the derived class override and/or hide member functions with the same name and parameter types in a base class (rather than conflicting).

Note that this wording doesn't mention any member function templates.

> p15 (C++11) When a *using-declaration* brings names from a base class into a derived class scope, member functions and member function templates in the derived class override and/or hide member functions and member function templates with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and *ref-qualifier* (if any) in a base class (rather than conflicting).

Note the mentioning of member function templates in the new wording. Also note, that the list that determines if a derived class member overrides / hides a base class member doesn't mention the *template-parameter-list* of the member function template as an identifying point, it is being ignored for this purpose.

I might be interpreting this completely wrong, but it seems Clang is the conforming compiler here, and GCC aswell as MSVC10 are non-conforming according to the new wording.

Comment: For a member function template, how is the parameter type list determined?  I mean, does template argument deduction take place?